# How can I forbid directory rename or move, while allowing file creation inside the directory?

Tags: linux, permissions

Example directory structure:

```
 /userA-directory/
        freespace-for-userA
        /THE-UNMOVABLE-UNRENAMABLE-PROTECTED-DIR/
             userA-files
             /userA-directories/
             freespace-for-userA
```

I want to give full write and create permissions inside the protected dir to some specific userA, but without letting userA rename or move that container dir. No touching the dirs name or location, but full freedom inside. And userA owns the parent directory as well.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

The current level of solution I could reach is this (with the help of @nobar):

How can I forbid a directories rename while allowing file creation operations inside and outside same directory?

Comment: Your example is more complex than your description.  What access do you want to provide for `various-userA-files-and-directories`?

Comment: Since I don't understand the question well enough to write an answer, I'll just give a hint: use the "GROUP" feature of Linux filesystems (see `chown` and `chmod` for starters).

Comment: Sorry for the complex example, I will simplify.

Comment: I don't see a way to do that directly.  You might be able to solve your problem by using a symbolic link to a directory at another location.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do, if I understand it, is quite common -- this is just creating a shared folder.

Maybe what you are missing is the fact that renaming a directory is *not* controlled by the same permission as modifying the contents of that directory -- the name of the shared directory is protected at the level of its parent directory.

In the simplest case, all you need to do is:

```
chmod o-w parent ## prevent others from modifying the parent directory
chmod o+rwx parent/THE-UNMOVABLE-UNRENAMABLE-PROTECTED-DIR ## others can write
```

But the preceding will allow *any* user to modify the shared directory.  For a more sophisticated setup you might manipulate the OWNER and/or GROUP of the target directory:

```
/parent -- OWNER:you, GROUP:you
   /THE-UNMOVABLE-UNRENAMABLE-PROTECTED-DIR/ -- OWNER:userA, GROUP:userA
      /userA-files-and-directories/ -- OWNER:userA, GROUP:userA
```

Use `chown` and/or `chmod` to manipulate the properties of `THE-UNMOVABLE-UNRENAMABLE-PROTECTED-DIR`.  You can see the properties using `ls -l`.

You might choose to set the OWNER and GROUP to separate values, but this is probably only necessary if you want to allow multiple users while also controlling who has access.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it is not exactly what I needed. The parent directory is userA space. I will clarify the question a bit more.